# Ancient Mars & Human Habitation

Tags: planets

**Editorial comment:** I tried deleting the original question, since in retrospect, and based on responses, it seemed to me to have been pointless asking it.  However, I could not delete it.

Hence this comment: My "bottom line" concern, I guess, was whether or not it would appear flat-out ridiculous to posit *an ancient Mars that could conceivably have supported human life*, with the planet having subsequently lost its atmosphere and liquid water.  I wanted to know whether that scenario could be presented "plausibly," albeit allowing for suspension-of-disbelief.

I think I got my answer, collectively, from those who responded.  So thanks.

:-)

---

*[Original question(s)]*

I'm considering the idea of ancient Mars having been inhabited by humans, then undergoing a cataclysm that ruined the environment and drove humans off-world to resettle on Earth.

Now, I may just concoct an "alternative history" which would involve an alternative "Mars" as well.  However, if I want to go with known real-world information and theories on ancient Mars . . .

- Could it have had seas at one point?
- Could it have had an atmosphere that humans, had they been there, could have breathed?
- Is the reported absence of limestone an indicator that, NO, humans could not have lived there at one point?

Go with hard science -- or "science-fantasy"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are asking 3 different questions, and with two different ways of answering them. We take only 1 question per post, and make up your mind beforehand if you want an hard science answer or a science fantasy one.

Comment: It's popularly believed that Mars once had water and an atmosphere, so there's nothing wrong with your idea.  But more to the point, hard science proving it simply doesn't exist. [The maps offer the strongest case yet that the planet once experienced sea-level rise consistent with an extended warm and wet climate](https://www.psu.edu/news/research/story/traces-ancient-ocean-discovered-mars/)! But that ain't hard science. So, even if you reword this to meet the [help]'s requirements, the best you're going to get is, "just do it."

Comment: OK, I've gotta say that another way. If you're worried that people won't believe your book, you've already failed because nobody believes humans lived on Mars. If you're worried that people won't believe your premise, then you've already succeeded because most people believe oceans and an atmosphere existed on ancient Mars. Therefore, to meet Stack Exchange's expectations for a specific problem to solve... what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Ahem, that's *Barsoom* to the locals. @JBH

Comment: @Escapeddentalpatient. +1 for the Edgar Rice Burroughs reference and a *very fair* point!

Answer (score 3):

**Nowhere close to hard-science**

The fossil record shows the first homo sapiens as being on Earth 200,000 to 300,000 years ago.  The first kind-of recognisable human ancestor, taking a very liberal approach to what is considered "human", was six million years ago.  The first vertebrates were only 500 million years ago.  Unfortunately for your proposed timeline, if Mars ever had a usefully dense atmosphere and free-standing water then it lost them *at least* 3 billion years ago.

It is unclear whether you are suggesting that:

1. humans are from Mars and moved to Earth, or
2. humans evolved on Earth, developed technology to get them to Mars, then abandoned Mars and returned to Earth, wiping out all traces of their high technology.

Either way, the timeframe does not work, since the appearance of vertebrates on Earth, let alone humans, is separated by billions of years from the era when Mars was less totally uninhabitable.  There is no point asking about what Martian conditions were exactly like billions of years ago when they definitely were *not* habitable within the last few million years that matter.

However, lack of hard science does not stop people (including me) getting invested in stories involving single-stage-to-orbit spaceships that fly all over the galaxy landing and taking off when they feel like it, yet they are just as scientifically implausible.  Write a good story and handwave the bits that do not fit the real universe, just like all the other authors.  (Even Andy Weir had to fudge the force exerted by Mars' atmosphere to get Mark Watney left behind, and The Martian is one of the most hard-science fiction books I have read recently.)